# bcp field terminator empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196735(v=sql.80).aspx

I'm trying to create a file from bcp, the file was successfully created, but I want to make the field terminator `-t` empty. The closest way was with the null terminator, but it makes a space between fields.

This is my code.

```
select @cmd = 'bcp '+ @SP + ' queryout '+ @ruta+' -w -t\0 -S '+@Servidor+ ' -U'+@user +' -P'+ @password
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

I've also tried to leave it without any symbol after `t`, but it puts more spaces.

```
select @cmd = 'bcp '+ @SP + ' queryout '+ @ruta+' -w -t -S '+@Servidor+ ' -U'+@user +' -P'+ @password
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Comment: have you tried without specifying a `-t` option at all?

Comment: If you're dead set on bcp, the best way I've heard to do this is to make a query or view which concatenates all your data into a single field.

Answer (score 1):

use `-t""` This basically gives you a fixed width export file especially when used to source fields defined as `char()`
 for example:
`bcp "select * from TEST.dbo.tExportTst" queryout FixedWidth.txt -c -t"" -T -S Svr\instance`